# Работа программы в фоновом режиме

Tags: visual-basic, visual-studio

Как скрыть заголовок скрытого окна программы во вкладке «Приложения» Диспетчера задач? То есть, чтобы иконка окна в панели задач видна была, а его заголовка окна в Диспетчере — нет.

Слышал, в Visual Basic можно задать свойство `App.TaskVisible = False`, а для Visual Studio аналогов я что-то не нашёл.

Comment: @BStudio Не забывайте принимать ответ, если он действительно отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @ХэшКод До чего же вы заботливые =D ... как мне нравится ваше сообщество.. Всё исправляете за новичками =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам значок в трей сделать можно с помощью NotifyIcon.

А форму прячет метод Hide(), показывает - Show().

Comment: Я думал, что NofityIcon - это элемент управления формы, он исчезнет вместе с ней. А попробовать как-то тямы нехватило.

Comment: реально всё работает. Спасибо.. хотя всё я это знал, просто заблуждался, не попробовав)))

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, диспетчер задач не показывает приложения, заголовок главного окна которых пустой. Можно попробовать выставить в значение заголовка пустую строку и посмотреть на результат.

```
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" _
                (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" _
                Alias "SetWindowTextA" _
                (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
Private Const GW_OWNER As Long = 4

Private Sub SetEmptyCaption()

Dim hOwner As Long
hOwner = GetWindow(Me.hwnd, GW_OWNER)

If hOwner <> 0 Then
    SetWindowText hOwner, ""
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я обязательно попробую. Только вот winapi зачем, если форма своя и можно написать Me.Text = "" 
... =D